# Symfony 3.3 and doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I have two entities `Article` and `Image` related by a ManytoMany relations using a third entity called `ArticlesHaveImages`.
I don't use classical ManytoMany relation of Doctrine because I have a third field in `ArticlesHaveImages` called sequence.

```
    class Article
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

    ...
    ...
        /**
         * One Article has Many articleHaveImage.
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticlesHaveImages", mappedBy="article")
         */
        private $images;


    class Image
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

     ...
    ...

        /**
         * One Image has Many articleHaveImage.
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticlesHaveImages", mappedBy="image")
         */
        private $articles;


        public function __construct() {
            $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
        }   

class ArticlesHaveImages
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Many ArticlesHaveImages have One Article.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * Many ArticlesHaveImages have One Image.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $image;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sequence", type="integer")
     */
    private $sequence;
```

How do I create a form out of this ?
I want a multiple select option which all images name.

I tried :

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $images = $options['images'];

        $builder
            ->add('translations', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => ArticleTranslationType::class,
                    'entry_options' => array('label' => false)))
            ->add('images', ChoiceType::class, array(
                "required" => false,
                "choices" => $images,
                'multiple' => true,
```

But I get :

> Could not determine access type for property "images" in class
>   "AppBundle\Entity\Article".

BIG THANKS !

Comment: Strange : the post delete the beginning of the post which was supposed to start with "hello"... impossible to edit it... Stackoverflow doesn't like me to be polite?  :-o

Comment: Do you have Article::get/setImages()?  This sort of thing can be very tricky.